# Supabase trigger not being called

Tags: postgresql, flutter, supabase, supabase-flutter

I'm following this guide [Build a User Management App with Flutter](https://%20https://supabase.com/docs/guides/getting-started/tutorials/with-flutter) and I'm at the[Storage Management](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/getting-started/tutorials/with-flutter#storage-management) section but even after enabling the http extension and defining the SQL functions in the SQL Editor to delete the user avatar when a new one is uploaded, nothing happens. The old avatar remains and a new one is created in the storage bucket. I don't see any error logs and I'm not sure I set it up correctly. I also ran each function at least once but they all returned success. These are the functions:

delete_storage_object

```
create or replace function delete_storage_object(bucket text, object text, out status int, out content text)
returns record
language 'plpgsql'
security definer
as $$
declare
  project_url text := '<YOURPROJECTURL>';
  service_role_key text := '<YOURSERVICEROLEKEY>'; --  full access needed
  url text := project_url||'/storage/v1/object/'||bucket||'/'||object;
begin
  select
      into status, content
           result.status::int, result.content::text
      FROM extensions.http((
    'DELETE',
    url,
    ARRAY[extensions.http_header('authorization','Bearer '||service_role_key)],
    NULL,
    NULL)::extensions.http_request) as result;
end;
$$;
```

delete_avatar

```
    create or replace function delete_avatar(avatar_url text, out status int, out content text)
    returns record
    language 'plpgsql'
    security definer
    as $$
    begin
      select
          into status, content
               result.status, result.content
          from public.delete_storage_object('avatars', avatar_url) as result;
    end;
    $$;

create or replace function delete_old_avatar()
returns trigger
language 'plpgsql'
security definer
as $$
declare
  status int;
  content text;
  avatar_name text;
begin
  if coalesce(old.avatar_url, '') <> ''
      and (tg_op = 'DELETE' or (old.avatar_url <> coalesce(new.avatar_url, ''))) then
    -- extract avatar name
    avatar_name := old.avatar_url;
    select
      into status, content
      result.status, result.content
      from public.delete_avatar(avatar_name) as result;
    if status <> 200 then
      raise warning 'Could not delete avatar: % %', status, content;
    end if;
  end if;
  if tg_op = 'DELETE' then
    return old;
  end if;
  return new;
end;
$$;

create trigger before_profile_changes
  before update of avatar_url or delete on public.profiles
  for each row execute function public.delete_old_avatar();
```

I would like to know how to fix this.

Comment: Just to double check, you have replaced `<YOURPROJECTURL>` and `<YOURSERVICEROLEKEY>` with your own, correct?

Comment: @dshukertjr yes I have.